# How to print n number of characters appearing after a searched character in BASH?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file like this:

```
Once upon a time, there lived a rabbit who lived in the forest.
One day, rabbit found bear.
Bear said, "Hello!"
```

Given a letter, e.g. "e", I need to output all searches for `e + the next 2 characters`, e.g., this will print the following:

```
e u
e, 
ere
e l
ed 
ed 
est
e d
ear
ear
ell
```

- Any character, including punctuation or symbols can be printed, but not a newline.
- This is case sensitive. If "e" is searched, it does not look for "E".

How can I print a searched for character plus the next 2 characters each time the searched character appears in a file in BASH?

Answer (score 3):

Can you use `perl`?

```
perl -lne 'print "e",$_ for $_ =~ /(?<=e)(..)/g' file
```

```
$ perl -lne 'print "e",$_ for $_ =~ /(?<=e)(..)/g' file
e u
e, 
ere
e l
ed 
ed 
e f
est
e d
ear
ear
ell
```

Answer (score 2):

To include overlapping strings, you can use this:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    while [ "${#line}" -gt 2 ]
    do
        if [ "${line:0:1}" = 'e' ]
        then
            echo "${line:0:3}"
        fi
        line="${line:1}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your grep supports -o, then it's easy

```
grep -o e..
```

Comment: This will not _include overlapping strings_, as l0b0 said!

Answer (score -1):

The hard way

```
echo $(cat file.txt ) > temp
grep -o . temp | nl | grep e | cut -f1 | xargs -i -n1 echo "{}; {} + 2;" | bc | xargs -n2 echo | sed 's/ /-/' |  xargs -i{} -n 1 cut -c {} temp
```

Comment: `echo $(cat file.txt ) > temp`: please, be serious.